# Cygwin - Obtaining new commands - Edit

Tags: linux, windows-8, cygwin, apt

I installed Cygwin to get the bash shell on window 8, and I'm not able to use `vim`, `ssh`, `apt`, `install` command. Many commands work now, while it didn't work in few minutes ago. What could I do to obtain those new command with Cygwin?

**EDIT :**

I know now I have to install `apt-cyg` using this [website](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg). This is exactly what I did, but even if the "apt-cyg file" is in the `Downloads` directory, I still don't know how to use this file to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

by default cygwin setup install only the packages in the `Base` category. If you need to install other packages you need to select them.

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages

To search which package contains what you are looking for, you can use the web search
https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi

or the command line one

```
cygcheck -p "file_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### I still don't know how to use this file to make it work.

Please read the `apt-cyg` readme, it tells you everything you need to know:

> **apt-cyg**
>
> `apt-cyg` is a Cygwin package manager. It includes a command-line
>   installer for Cygwin which cooperates with Cygwin Setup and uses the
>   same repository.
>
> github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg
>
> ```
> Operations
>
> install
>   Install package(s).
>
> remove
>   Remove package(s) from the system.
>
> update
>   Download a fresh copy of the master package list (setup.ini) from the
>   server defined in setup.rc.
>
> download
>   Retrieve package(s) from the server, but do not install/upgrade anything.
>
> show
>   Display information on given package(s).
>
> depends
>   Produce a dependency tree for a package.
>
> rdepends
>   Produce a tree of packages that depend on the named package.
>
> list
>   Search each locally-installed package for names that match regexp. If no
>   package names are provided in the command line, all installed packages will
>   be queried.
>
> listall
>   This will search each package in the master package list (setup.ini) for
>   names that match regexp.
>
> category
>   Display all packages that are members of a named category.
>
> listfiles
>   List all files owned by a given package. Multiple packages can be specified
>   on the command line.
>
> search
>   Search for downloaded packages that own the specified file(s). The path can
>   be relative or absolute, and one or more files can be specified.
>
> searchall
>   Search cygwin.com to retrieve file information about packages. The provided
>   target is considered to be a filename and searchall will return the
>   package(s) which contain this file.
> ```
>
> **Quick start**
>
> apt-cyg is a simple script. To install:
>
> ```
> lynx -source rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg > apt-cyg
> install apt-cyg /bin
> ```
>
> Example use of apt-cyg:
>
> ```
> apt-cyg install nano
> ```

Source [readme.md](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/blob/master/readme.md)